# I am creating graph using plotly, However i am not sure how to do it for india, below is the code for US in python

Tags: flask, heroku, plotly-python, choropleth

I am using Cloropleth function and a dictionary for states and their short forms

```
figure = {'data': [go.Choropleth(  # colorscale = "Blues",
    locations=geo_dist['State'],
        z=geo_dist['Log Num'].astype(float),
        locationmode='USA-states',
        text=geo_dist['text'],
        geo='geo',
        colorbar_title='Num in Log2',
        marker_line_color='white',
        colorscale=['#fdf7ff', '#835af1'],
        )], 'layout': {'title': 'Geographic Segmentation for US',
                       'geo': {'scope': 'asia'}}}
```

This is done for US, I want for India

Answer (score 0):

- fundamentally if you want to use geometry that is not included in **plotly** you need to provide *geojson*
- have found source of geojson that defined geometry for Indian states
- you reference a data frame in you sample code, so I have simulated it
- then a simple case of linking data frame to geometry using **locations** and **featureidkey**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

r = requests.get("https://www.geoboundaries.org/gbRequest.html?ISO=IND&ADM=ADM1")
india = requests.get(r.json()[0]["gjDownloadURL"]).json()


geo_dist = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["text", "State"],
    data=[
        ["Tamil Nadu", "IN-TN"],
        ["Puducherry", "IN-PY"],
        ["Himachal Pradesh", "IN-HP"],
        ["Uttarakhand", "IN-UT"],
        ["Sikkim", "IN-SK"],
        ["Delhi", "IN-DL"],
        ["Uttar Pradesh", "IN-UP"],
        ["Haryana", "IN-HR"],
        ["Punjab", "IN-PB"],
        ["Chandigarh", "IN-CH"],
        ["Rajasthan", "IN-RJ"],
        ["Jammu and Kashmir", "IN-JK"],
        ["Gujarat", "IN-GJ"],
        ["Madhya Pradesh", "IN-MP"],
        ["Maharashtra", "IN-MH"],
        ["Union Territory of Dadra & Nagar Haveli", "IN-DN"],
        ["Daman and Diu", "IN-DD"],
        ["Bihar", "IN-BR"],
        ["West Bengal", "IN-WB"],
        ["Jharkhand", "IN-JH"],
        ["Chhattisgarh", "IN-CT"],
        ["Odisha", "IN-OR"],
        ["Goa", "IN-GA"],
        ["Kerala", "IN-KL"],
        ["Karnataka", "IN-KA"],
        ["Andhra Pradesh", "IN-AP"],
        ["Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "IN-AN"],
        ["Assam", "IN-AS"],
        ["Tripura", "IN-TR"],
        ["Arunachal Pradesh", "IN-AR"],
        ["Lakshadweep", "IN-LD"],
        ["Meghalaya", "IN-ML"],
        ["Manipur", "IN-MN"],
        ["Nagaland", "IN-NL"],
        ["Mizoram", "IN-MZ"],
        ["Telangana", "IN-TG"],
    ],
)
geo_dist["Log Num"] = np.random.uniform(1, 10, len(geo_dist))
figure = {
    "data": [
        go.Choropleth(  # colorscale = "Blues",
            locations=geo_dist["State"],
            featureidkey="properties.shapeISO",
            geojson=india,
            z=geo_dist["Log Num"].astype(float),
            # locationmode="USA-states",
            text=geo_dist["text"],
            geo="geo",
            colorbar_title="Num in Log2",
            marker_line_color="white",
            colorscale=["#fdf7ff", "#835af1"],
        )
    ],
    "layout": {
        "title": "Geographic Segmentation for India",
        "geo": {"fitbounds": "locations"},
    },
}

go.Figure(figure)
```

[image]